# trying to add a new product but its not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to save my new product items. my condition was if the new Product has an id it will go for an update, else no id then it will go for the **addProduct** method and will add new products. But all time it's going to **updateProduct** method so it gets some id.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping_app/providers/product.dart';
import 'product.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 25.25,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy, what you need for winter',
      price: 30.00,
      imageUrl:
          'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/yellow-knitted-scarf-18952858.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'A pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want',
      price: 20.20,
      imageUrl:
          'https://5.imimg.com/data5/CS/XL/MY-910175/master-non-stick-frypan-500x500.png',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'Trouser',
      description: 'Any style goes beyond',
      price: 10.50,
      imageUrl:
          'https://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/36206203_l.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favouriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavourite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  void addProduct(Product product) {
    final newProduct = Product(
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      title: product.title,
      description: product.description,
      price: product.price,
      imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
    );
    _items.add(newProduct); //end at the list
    //_items.insert(0, newProduct); // begining at the list
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) {  //provlem is here when i save the form for new products it always goes to else condition
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...'); // when i save the from  for new product then it always go to my updateProduct and could not find the product and ends with print else 
    }
  }

  void deleteProduct(String id) {
    _items.removeWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image: This my addProduct and updateProduct method]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/product_provider.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = ('/editProduct');
  EditProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusedNode = FocusNode();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: null.toString(),
    title: '',
    description: '',
    price: 0,
    imageUrl: '',
  );
  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };
  var _isInit = true;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    // _imageUrlFocusedNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusedNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusedNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedProduct =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId);
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (!_imageUrlFocusedNode.hasFocus) {
      if (_imageUrlController.text.isEmpty ||
          (!_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
          (_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.png') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpg') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpeg'))) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    //i think i am having problem here my conditon was if product has id the if condition will take us to the edited product
    // or eles condition which will add new product. But i found that when i save new product and go to the updateProduct
    final _isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (!_isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    print(_editedProduct.id);
    print(_editedProduct.title);
    print(_editedProduct.price);
    print(_editedProduct.description);
    print(_editedProduct.imageUrl);

    if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    }

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Product'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: _saveForm,
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Title',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    id: _editedProduct.id,
                    title: value.toString(),
                    description: _editedProduct.description,
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    isFavourite: _editedProduct.isFavourite,
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter Title.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Price',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    id: _editedProduct.id,
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    description: _editedProduct.description,
                    price: double.parse(value!),
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    isFavourite: _editedProduct.isFavourite,
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter a price';
                  }
                  if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                    return 'Valid Number';
                  }
                  if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                    return 'Enter a price gatter then zero';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Description',
                ),
                maxLines: 3,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    id: _editedProduct.id,
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    description: value.toString(),
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    isFavourite: _editedProduct.isFavourite,
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter a descriotion';
                  }
                  if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Please enter at least 10 characters';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                        ? Text('Enter an URL')
                        : FittedBox(
                            child: Image.network(_imageUrlController.text),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      controller: _imageUrlController,
                      focusNode: _imageUrlFocusedNode,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        _saveForm();
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                          description: _editedProduct.description,
                          price: _editedProduct.price,
                          imageUrl: value.toString(),
                          isFavourite: _editedProduct.isFavourite,
                        );
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Enter an image URL';
                        }
                        if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                            !value.startsWith('https')) {
                          return 'Enter an address with http/https';
                        }
                        if (value.endsWith('.png') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                          return 'Enter png/jpg/jpeg format ';
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think my problem is here because when I give id=null is demand
**id: null.toString()**so I think **tostring()** itself giving some random/garbage value for my id that's why when it goes to **_saveForm()** method it already has some random/garbage value that's why it choose the **if** condition then its goes for **updateProduct** method instate of going to **else** condition where its need to choose the **addProduct** method to add new products.So that's why when I submit the form is not working and does not add any new product.
[image: for Id to be null]

this is my edited product screen where I used to save the product and update it. It contains my **onSave** method where I write the **if-else** condition. if a product has id then it will go to **updateProduct**  else it will go for **addProduct**.

[image: on save method]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue I've solved in this way.

First, initialize a bool variable `bool isNew = true;` the only two methods I've changed are:

1. `didChangeDependencies`
2. `_saveForm`

For the `didChangeDependeies()` function here is the code:

```
void didChangeDependencies() {
  if (_isInit) {
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
    if (productId != null) {
      isNew = false;
      _editedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .findById(productId.toString());
      _initValues = {
        'title': _editedProduct.title,
        'description': _editedProduct.description,
        'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
        'imageUrl': '',
      };
      _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
    }
  }
  _isInit = false;
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

As you can see, `isNew` is set to `false`.

And for the `saveForm` function:

```
void _saveForm() {
  final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
  if (!isValid) {
    return;
  }
  _form.currentState!.save();

  if (isNew) {
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_editedProduct);
  } else {
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
      .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
  }
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

I have removed `_editedProduct.id != null` and replaced with `isNew var`, if the product is new add item if not update item.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but could you remove your null initialization? In my old code, I haven't it.

```
    @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final prodId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
      if (prodId != null) {
        _editedProduct = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .findById(prodId);
        _initValue = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

You told me before about some changes. But my old code totally works. You can check it on my repository https://github.com/Spiritfaer/shop_app

Also, you can add links to your repository. It can be helpful for another developer who wants to help you.

Comment: it's not working bro.  Problem with id which is getting some random value. is there another way?? @Igor Michael Stalevskiy

Comment: bro if you go to save method you will see if and else statement. where if there is an existing id it will go for the update product method, else there is no id which means that I want to create a new product then it will go add product method.  but problem is that my product getting some id anyhow but I can not find the error where It's occurring. @ Igor Michael Stalevskiy

Comment: 1.check the ID you get here
`_editedProduct = Provider.of <ProductsProvider> (context, listen: false).findById (prodId);`

2. check if this ID and ID match in the _saveForm () method.

3. Use breakpoints to track the state of your objects