# Unable to add new product

Tags: flutter, dart

I still get update new product but when I add a new product nothing happen so what's the problem, pls help me. Thanks

```
void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign an empty String to the 'id' argument of _editedProduct, then change this condition "if (_editedProduct.id != null)" to this "if (_editedProduct.id.isNotEmpty)".

You should be able to add a new product after this.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the product id would be a string which is assigned empty string if null. So when checking the condition try this

```
if (_editedProduct.id != null && _editedProduct.id.isNotEmpty) {
}
```

Comment: Still not work sir

Comment: Can you try printing the _editedProduct just above the if condition and add the print log here please

Comment: Here sir : I/flutter (10378): Instance of 'Product'

Comment: print(json.encode(_editedProduct));

Comment: i don't use json in this project sir

Comment: I wanted to see the content of edited product especially the id when you are trying to add a new product

Comment: i have same problem like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553952/trying-to-add-a-new-product-but-its-not-working?rq=1